# How to NAT ports on VPS connected to distant network through OpenVPN

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn, vps, nat

Could you please tell me what IPTABLES rules i should write to my VPS (running Debian 8) to do NAT on port 8082?

I need port 8082 to be addressed a local device on my LAN (192.168.0.100)

User should browse VPS public IP.

An OpenVPN tunel is established from VPS to local network (A Synology NAS acts as VPN client)

I did try to add the following to IPTABLES but port 8082 still closed and it does not let any user reach the local device from VPS public IP:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8082 -j DNAT --to 10.0.1.10:8082
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.1.10 --dport 8082 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is my network schematic:

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: Please see my network schematic here]